# How to bind entity to different tables with SpringJPA/SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to design a system. There are different customers using this system. I need to create the duplicated tables for every customer. For example, I have a table `Order`, then all of order records for `customerA` are in table `Order_A`, as well as `customerB` data are in table `Order_B`. I can distinct different customers from session, but how can I let Spring JPA to reflect the RDS table data to Java object?

I know 2 solutions, but both are not satisfied.

1. Consider to use Mybatis because it supports load SQL from xml file and parameters inside SQL;
2. Consider to use `org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor`. This is my current implement in my project. For every entity, I must define a subclass of it. It can update the SQL before Hibernate's execution.
   However, both are not graceful. I prefer the better solution.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible how you want it. There are different ways. 1. Multiple datasources, one for each customer. 2. Add a field to `Order` that distinguishes by customer

Comment: Your solution doesn't sound so good, maybe in your Order table you should have a field with the Costumer's id as foreign key. You should have a @ManyToOne relationship.

Comment: @OctaviaAdler There is a risk to store all of customers' orders into a single table. If the developer forget to filter, a customer could query out other's orders. This is very dangerous.